# Using Django to display images

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am attempting to use Django to display 3 random images from a large list of user submitted images. Each image has other values associated with it like the author, so I've been making each image a model with the image field holding the image itself. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to randomly pick from that list and pass it in to the .html page to display it correctly.

So far, I've been able to get user submitted pictures to be saved as models and submitted to a folder `/media/images/`.
 My `views.py` will grab 3 random and unique pictures from that folder like so:

```
def home_view(request):
    form = MForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    message_list = MModel.objects.all()

    #Get first random file
    file1choice = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))

    #Get second random file
    file2choice = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))
    while(file2choice == file1choice):
        file2choice = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))

    #Get third random file
    file3choice = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))
    while(file3choice == file1choice or file3choice == file2choice):
        file3choice = random.choice(os.listdir(DIR))


    context = {
        'file1': file1choice,
        'file2': file2choice,
        'file3': file3choice,
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

In my .html file that the user sees, I access each image passed like so:
`<img src="/media/images/{{ file1 }}" width="300" height="180" alt="">`

**Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to actually access the model of the image itself, which means I can't also display the associated values of the image. I'm just grabbing random stuff using python.**

So, my question is **how would I pass along to the .html file 3 random image models and how would I display that in the .html itself?**

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MModel(models.Model):
    Message = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import MModel
from django import forms

class MForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MModel
        fields = ['Message', 'Img', 'Author']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could just pass in the randomly selected object itself,

```
#Some uniquely random file 1
choice1 = random.choice(message_list)

#Some uniquely random file 2
choice2 = random.choice(message_list)
while(choice2 == choice1):
    choice2 = random.choice(message_list)

#Some uniquely random file 3
choice3 = random.choice(message_list)
while(choice3 == choice1 or choice3 == choice2):
    choice3 = random.choice(message_list)
```

This means I can access the object's image (and other attributes) in the .html like so:
`<img src="/media/{{ aPassedFile.Img }} " width="290" height="180" alt="">`